# Read DigitalProductId Value From Windows Registry in Ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, registry, regedit

So far i have this code

```
require 'win32/registry'


Win32::Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.open('Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion',Win32::Registry::KEY_ALL_ACCESS) do |reg|

 puts reg['DigitalProductId']

end
```

But it doesn't allow me to get the DigitalProductId value. Some of the values are available but some of them are not.

```
CurrentVersion
CurrentBuild
SoftwareType
CurrentType
InstallDate
RegisteredOrganization
RegisteredOwner
SystemRoot
InstallationType
EditionID
ProductName
CurrentBuildNumber
BuildLab
BuildLabEx
BuildGUID
CSDBuildNumber
PathName
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because you are running on 64 bit Machine. it could not identify the key "DigitalProductId" from the registry untill you change the TragetPlatform to X64 bit CPU.

Hope it helps

Comment: Can u provide an example?